# Some recipients receive mosaico emails with different (broken) formatting

Tags: mosaico

our site uses mosaico. some email recipients complain about about formatting, where text is unreadable (because is rendered in black on a dark background) and images are broken up strangely. This seems to have something to do with individual devices because I do not have the same issue when testing on my desktop or mobile device (I thought it was about dark mode, but actually, on my iphone our emails look fine in darkmode).

Has anyone encountered this and know how to solve?

Comment: can you check what they are using to read their emails?

Comment: hi @petednz-fuzion, they are viewing the email on their Dell PC through Outlook. When the email is forwarded to me, I can see the wonky formatting, but I am not able to see the wonky formatting by sending the same email to myself from civi